# Using Places Library in App maker

Tags: google-places-api, google-app-maker

Is there a way to call PlacesServices' getDetails function from App Maker?
I have the Place ID from the Geocoder but I'd like to be able to get details about the place.

Comment: Can you please post sample of your code, show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time there is no built-in Places service in Apps Script and you'll need to through these steps to make it work:

1. Go to [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com)
2. Create a brand new project or use the project associated with your App Maker deployment:
   [image: View Logs]
3. Using left navigation menu go to `APIs & Services -> Dashboard`
   [image: GCP]
4. Click `+ Enable APIs and Services` button
5. Search for `Google Places API Web Service` and enable it
6. Go to `APIs & Services -> Credentials` and create new API key if you don't have one
7. Back in App Maker! =) Create a server script:

```javascript
var API_KEY = 'PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE';
var PLACES_URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';

function getPlaceDetails_(placeId) {
  var URL = PLACES_URL + placeId + '&key=' + API_KEY;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeDetails = JSON.parse(json);

  return placeDetails;
}
```

This snippet is cornerstone for further scripting. You can use it with [Calculated Model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/calculated) or just call it using [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) from client (**note** that for the second case you'll need to make this [function public](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions) by removing underscore in the end of function name).

Comment: Super - I was hoping the library was built in but this works, thanks!